PyMuPDF Generate a multi-query invoice
Using one of the examples from PyMuPDF on generating an invoice, and am having issues generating multiple tables on one page, each with a different sqlite3 query. I can get the data in the tables, and they do display, just each on it's own page with the header. I can even change the header to generate one table, and the report.sections do one more, but the third is on another page and I lose the header of course.
invoicer.py
import pathlib
import sqlite3

import fitz

from Reports import *

# The following defines the overall report object
mediabox = fitz.paper_rect("a4-l")
report = Report(mediabox)

# Predefined HTML to define the header for all pages
hdr_html = pathlib.Path("header.html").read_bytes().decode()
header = Block(html=hdr_html, report=report)

# define a logo image to become part of the header
logo = ImageBlock(url="logo.png", height=80, report=report)

# Prepare the "prolog" for page 1. Following data would normally be
# exctracted from a data base.
supplier = """Artifex Software, Inc.
39 Mesa Street
Suite 108A
San Francisco, CA 94129
UNITED STATES
"""

contact = """Artifex Software, Inc.
39 Mesa Street
Suite 108A
San Francisco, CA 94129
UNITED STATES
"""

shipto = """Paul Atreides (Muad'Dib)
The Emperor's Palace
Arrakeen
Planet Arrakis (Dune)
"""

billto = """Jorj X. McKie, Saboteur Extraordinary
Bureau of Sabotage
Central City
Planet Central-Central
"""

# The prolog HTML basically is a skeleton with 4 variables
prolog_html = pathlib.Path("prolog.html").read_bytes().decode()

# After reading the source, we access the content and fill in
# data for the variables.
prolog_story = fitz.Story(prolog_html)
body = prolog_story.body
body.find(None, "id", "supplier").add_text(supplier)
body.find(None, "id", "contact").add_text(contact)
body.find(None, "id", "billto").add_text(billto)
body.find(None, "id", "shipto").add_text(shipto)

# Now define the building block.
# Because we modified the HTML, we use the prepared Story instead of the
# original HTML source.
prolog = Block(story=prolog_story, report=report)


def fetch_rows():
    """Read and return invoice items.

    This is a callback function called by the report generator.
    In the general case, any type of data could be accessed here,
    like JSON, CSV, or other databases.

    In our example, we are reading an sqlite database und manipulate
    the rows a bit before returning them.
    """
    database = sqlite3.connect("invoice-parms.db")  # contains invoice items
    cursor = database.cursor()  # make a cursor

    # Extract invoice items
    # Note that the last items is computed by SQL!
    select = (
        'select line, "hp-id", desc, part,qty, uom,date,'
        "uprice, qty*uprice"
        ' from "invoice-items" order by line'
    )
    cursor.execute(select)  # read the invoice items into a list
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # we need some modifications for the report:
    field_count = len(rows[0])  # number of fields
    total = 0  # total price of the invoice
    for i in range(len(rows)):  # walk through the rows
        row = list(rows[i])  # make sure to have a modifiable list
        uprice, tprice = row[-2:]  # read the prices
        total += tprice  # add to the total prices
        # modify items to show the currency
        row[-1] = f"${tprice}"
        row[-2] = f"${uprice}"
        rows[i] = row  # update the rows list

    # add a final row with the invoice total
    total_row = [""] * field_count
    total_row[-2] = "Total:"
    total_row[-1] = f"${round(total,2)}"

    # append the totals row
    rows.append(total_row)

    # prepend a row with the HTML field id's:
    fields = [  # 'id' items in the HTML source
        "line",
        "hp-id",
        "desc",
        "part",
        "qty",
        "uom",
        "date",
        "uprice",
        "tprice",
    ]
    rows.insert(0, fields)
    return rows


# Read the HTML source code for the items table
items_html = pathlib.Path("items.html").read_bytes().decode()

items = Table(  # generate a table object that can cross page boundaries
    html=items_html,  # HTML source
    fetch_rows=fetch_rows,  # callback to fetch invoice items
    top_row="header",  # identifies the table's top row
    report=report,  # pointer to owning report object
    last_row_bg="#ff0",  # background color of last row
)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# We have defined all required building blocks for the report.
# Now define on which pages they should be used.
# Report type "FrontMatterReport" supports this by two separate lists
# of building blocks:
# One for the first page and one for all other pages.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

report.header = [logo, header]
report.sections = [
    [prolog, Options(cols=1, format="letter-l")],
    [items, Options(format=Size(600, 600), newpage=False)],
]

# This generates the report and saves it to the given path name.
report.run("output.pdf")


I have added separate locations to the report but cannot get them all on one page.
Each table is only about 6 rows so I know they will fit. Basically I need 3 tables with three different product variations and their totals in the end.
I have tried-
report.header = [logo, header,]
    report.sections = [
        #[prolog, Options(cols=1, format="letter-l")],
        [items, Options(format=Size(600, 600), newpage=False)],
        [items2, Options(format=Size(600, 600), newpage=True)],
        [items3, Options(format=Size(600, 600), newpage=False)],
    ]

Items 2 and 3 are just a clone of Items, with a different query.
If there is a different templating option I could do that as well, but this one does most of what I need.
On a side note I updated to the latest version 1.24.2 and now all the page numbers are upside down and inverted at the top of the page now, so if you have a fix for that, as I am not seeing one currently.
